# Что такое абстракция в компонентной системе vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, терминология

Например:

> Компонентная система является ещё одной важной концепцией во Vue, потому что это **абстракция**, которая позволяет создавать большие приложения, состоящие из небольших, автономных и часто переиспользуемых компонентов. Если задуматься, то практически любой тип интерфейса приложения можно **абстрактно** представить деревом компонентов.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Учебник прочитали? Что именно вам непонятно?

Comment: Абстракция в программировании бывает только в ООП, или не только? Просто этот термин часто употребляют. При этом было не совсем понятно что это.

Comment: @Muriam не только. Даже разбиение кода на процедуры/функции - это уже абстрагирование. Еще пример: уровни сетевых моделей - это тоже уровни абстракции (например, вместо взаимодействия между клиентом и сервером на отдельных уровне TCP пакетов, мы посылаем HTTP запросы).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Абстракция в целом - это антоним конкретизации / реализации.
Абстракцией в программировании называется **скрытие или игнорирование подробностей реализации**.

Абстрагируя какую-то сущность или процесс, мы выделяем общие неизменные характеристики... и отбрасываем индивидуальные, которые могут быть несвойственны другим экземплярам того же типа.
Зачем нужна абстракция: для того понимать общие принципы (в обучении/исследовании), и проектировать их воплощение (в практическом применении).

---

Пример из реального мира, *абстракция* яблока: фрукт округлой формы, растущий на яблонях, обладающий кисло-сладким вкусом.
Яблоки бывают более сладкие, бывают более кислые, бывают разных цветов и размеров - все это характеризует *классы* яблок, класс определяет общие свойства группы уже конкретных объектов, а не абстракции (сорт яблок можно назвать их классом, еще можно придумать и свой класс как "краснодарские крупные сладкие", это уже не так важно). Яблоко которое например лежит перед тобой на столе, это конкретный *экземпляр* яблока (реализованный объект) - как с общими свойствами его абстрактной модели и класса (сорта/признака), так и с индивидуальными свойствами (присущими только этому конкретному яблоку, и никакому другому).

---

Так, абстракция сущности "компонент" автоматически предполагает что это какая-то составная часть (другой сущности), вероятно переиспользуемая, и вероятно имеющая собственные характеристики (свойства).
Если мы говорим не о конкретном компоненте, то подразумеваем общее понятие - то есть, абстрагируемся от каких-то конкретных компонентов в каких-то конкретных системах.

Компонентный интерфейс - интерфейс, состоящий из компонентов. Это абстрактное определение: оно не говорит *какой* интерфейс, не говорит *какие* компоненты. Смысл таков, что если представить интерфейс в общем (не какой-то конкретный), то мы можем мысленно разделить его на части, и эти части могут быть представлены разнообразными компонентами (не обязательно только какими-то конкретными). То есть, мы создали теорию: любой интерфейс может быть представлен набором составляющих его компонентов - эта теория выделяет общее свойство сущности интерфейса, обнаруженное через абстрагирование множества интерфейсов в их общую "виртуальную модель".

*// Для понимания абстрактной модели компонентного интерфейса в виде дерева, надо понимать что из себя представляет дерево (вид графов, не растение) - а это уже за рамками вопроса, поэтому я не буду тут вдаваться в детали.*

Answer (score 0):

Если очень сильно упростить, Абстракция - это правильное разделение программы на объекты. Абстракция позволяет отобрать главные характеристики и опустить второстепенные.

Comment: Вы перепутали с декомпозицией